# Simple math addition in JS giving wrong result

Tags: javascript, jquery, math

I have this strange problem I can't get my head around. I try to find the highest number in a list of elements which have a `data-index` attribute for their respective number. But when iterating over them, JS insists that `9 < 10` is false.
See this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/1ztbxbjx/

What I'm doing wrong?

I can't use

`for (i = 0; i < $('div[data-index]'; i++))`

Sometimes there will be numbers out of order in the list (eg. 1,2,3,4,5,25,31).

Comment: looks like you are doing a string comparison

Comment: those indexes are returning strings. they are not true numbers you will need to convert the string to a number.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to parse the id, otherwise you're comparing strings. Here is an [example](http://jsfiddle.net/depperm/gtqpetg5/) using `parseInt()`

Comment: *couldn't remember the function off top my head so didn't want to do an answer. kudos to you*

Answer (score 1):

Use this

`if (indexCount < parseInt(current)) {`

instead of

`if (indexCount < current) {`

Answer (score 1):

Parse retreived id to Number and it should work fine, try this:

```
var current = Number($(this).attr('id'));
```

Tested in JSFiddle, its working fine after this one line change.

Cheers !